# Does Satmar have their own form of Chassidus?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, satmar

I know Satmar is a chassidic group. But do they have their own form of chassidus? Other chassidic groups like Chabad, Ger etc. all have their own chassidus, does Satmar?

( *A "form of chassidus" is the theological thought that combines esoteric kabbalistic texts with the more commonly studied texts; ie Gemara* )

Answer (score 4):

Satmar, with the name Satmar, started with Rabbi Yoel Teitelbaum. Their Chassidus comes through his father (who was a Rebbe in Siget and who's Chassidus came through the Chozeh of Lublin).

However, Rabbi Teitelbaum himself famously held that Nishtachach Toras HaBa'al Shem Tov - the Torah of the Ba'al Shem Tov was forgotten.

So it may be correct to say that they don't have one, or in the alternative you could look at Rabbi Teitelbaum's Haskafah as their Chassidus. It is certainly as well defined as most any Chassidus.

Comment: How do you understand  Nishtachach Toras HaBa'al Shem Tov? And of course the other side of the Machlokes? If you think it will be too long I can ask it as a question which you can answer.

Comment: If their chassidus is as well defined as anyone's, then how could it be correct to say that they don't have a chassidus? With each chassidic group, don't we just say that the teachings of their rebbes constitute the chassidus of that group? In the case of Satmar, by the way, I understand that they allow or encourage their chassidim to learn other chassidic seforim other than Satmar (such as Breslov), so they don't necessarily insist on learning only certain seforim.

Comment: @Kordovero, I said their *Hashkafah* is as well defined.

Comment: @user6591, I'm not going to authoritatively say, but my understanding is that the point is that the philosophy and underlying view of the Ba'al Shem Tov is not accurately understood.

Comment: Yishai, my Lubavitch brotha from a nutha mutha, don't wiggle out like that. What was Baal Shem's philosophy that Reb Menachem Mendel and Reb Yoel were arguing if it is still understood? I'm sure it can be summarized, and I'm sure Reb M.M. explained why it is still valid, and I'm sure Reb Y. explained why it is not. I am very curious what the give and take was. Is there somewhere or something I can read that delves into this?

Comment: @user6591, you want to know what Chassidus is? I recommend [Kuntres Inyana Shel Toras Hachassidus](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/admur/inyono/1). In terms of some direct back and forth argument, I'm not aware of any, but don't take me as authoritative on that.

Comment: I've read a few pages. From what I see it is very parve, meaning I don't think there is anything there that a Lubavitcher would seem to conform to any more than a Satmar, and for that matter the average yeshiva guy. There is nothing there in thought or act that would separate any two groups.

Comment: @user6591, My point is that the idea that someone knows, understands and can teach the ideas of Chassidus as the Chiddush described was what I understood him to mean was forgotten. I'm sure the "average yeshiva guy" (meaning a non-Chossid) would disagree with the thesis there - or he would probably learn Chassidus.

Comment: The average yeshiva guy is opposed to chassidus as a cultural  throwback perhaps to when people were aware of a difference. But qhen you talk to him or a satmar or a lubavitch, their hashkofos are all the same. Accommitment to living life according to Torah law, and a belief in deeper mystical ideas associated with kabbala and chassidus. I've had many long conversations with my chassidish friends and the one difference left between chassidish and yeshivish is a rebbe's tish. And it vould be the yeshivish version of that is shiur klali once a week.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66332/reb-yoels-opinion-on-torah-of-baal-shem-tov#66332